# Prioritized experience replay correction with off-policy estimators

Tags: reinforcement-learning, off-policy-methods, experience-replay

Prioritized exeperience replay (PER) biases the sampling and introduces importance sampling (IS) correction to the Q-function update.
Weights are $w = \frac{1}{N P}^\beta$, where $N$ is the batch size and $P$ is the sampling probability.

Off-policy estimators like Retrace and V-Trace also use IS correction between the behavior and the target policy. Weights are $w = \pi / \mu$, where $\pi$ is the target policy and $\mu$ is the behavior policy. Weights are further clipped.

Recent methods like APE-X, Reactor, and LASER combine both techniques: they use a replay memory where n-step samples are drawn to compute value function target with off-policy estimators.

However, it is unclear to me how they combine off-policy correction and PER correction.
**How are weights from off-policy estimators and weights from PER combined in methods like APE-X, Reactor, and LASER?**